# SQL - How to search WHERE but ignore first two characters

Tags: sql

I need to perform a date search but the data is a String with the format

'dd/mm/yyyy'

I want to search only for 'mm/yyyy'

For example I want all records that have '07/2014' regardless of what day?

I'm sure its something simple just can't figure it out

**EDIT**: 
It looks like the format is MM/DD/YYY
Looks like I got this sorted just used:

```
RIGHT(BookedDate,5) = '/2014'
AND LEFT (BookedDate,2) = '7/'
```

Thanks All :)

Comment: What RDBMS?  Lots of choices, depending.  `RIGHT`,'SUBSTRING`,...

Comment: Why is it a string ? Can you change that?

Comment: The data that comes in is just in string format (Not my choice)

Comment: The data always comes in string format, the question is that `how it is stored?`

Comment: Another question goes officially 'Unanswered'

Answer (score 2):

If your string is in the format of `dd/mm/yyyy` always, as in `01/09/2014` you could use right:

```
declare @val as varchar(10)
Set @val='1/2/2014'
RIGHT(@val,7)
```

if you are not sure of the format but know that there is a `/` you could search for it:

```
declare @val as varchar(10)
Set @val='1/2/2014'
select right(@val,len(@val)-patindex('%/%',@val))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myfield like '%/07/2014'
```

Beware, since the wildcard (%) is put at the beginning of the query no indexes (if they exist) will be used. This will always be a full table scan.

Comment: this also will avoid `n` number of leading characters, not 2 as the OP requested

Answer (score 0):

If you store your date values in `character` based column, than **jyparask's** answer is good enough, but if you store it in `date/time` based column, then use date/time functions or intervals:

```
WHERE
  myDateColumn >= '01/07/2014'
  AND myDateColumn < '01/08/2014'
```

The above `WHERE` condition means: all values in July, 2014.

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure that, because its a string, if the value is longer than expected the first three characters will always be removed.

```
  SELECT RIGHT(field, LEN(field)-3) FROM database
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a very bad idea. Most likely there is a ton of optimizations that could be done automatically for your queries by the database if you used Date instead of the String.
This is certainly going to be some kind of bottleneck if your database grows, it would have to ask and parse every single row to find out if it matches your request.